# Get JSON object from URL

Tags: php, json, decode, file-get-contents

I am having problems in getting the consumption data from the following json object:

```
{"version":"0.3","data":{"uuid":"010f5190-83a4-11e4-98cd-d9350366ee4b","from":1423262668135,"to":1454790652371,"min":[1454790652371,27.11945025092],"max":[1454790652371,27.11945025092],"average":27.119,"consumption":237506,"rows":362,"tuples":[[1454790652371,27.119,41140]]}}
```

I would like to echo the consumption data `"237506"` but do not get any results.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://vz.xx.de/middleware.php/data/010f5190-83a4-11e4-98cd-d9350366ee4b.json?from=1+year+ago&group=day&tuples=1';
$string = file_get_contents($url, true);
$result = json_decode($string);
echo $result->consumption;

?>
```

If I echo `$result->version` it works without problems...

Comment: Have you tried $result->data->consumption; ? Because consumption is into data object

Comment: Try to var_dump($result) after $result = json_decode($string)

Comment: try `echo $result->data->consumption;`

Comment: When in doubt: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: thanks, that worked!

Comment: @alx please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks.

Comment: @alx please mark the answer for others help

Comment: Peoples are saying it worked. But not interested in marking and up-voting the answer for others help. wastage of work. deleting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just tidied the JSON and realised that consumption is within the data key.

```
{
    "version": "0.3",
    "data": {
        ...
        "consumption": 237506,
        ...
    }
}
```

This is why you can't access it. Try `$result->data` first then get your data from this object/array